# how to write formatted text in a rectangle using quartz framework in iphone

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics

I m a newbie in iphone. 
Currently m doing a project to create a pdf having tables. 
I created that. I can even write the text in table cells. 
But now the problem is the data will come dynamically from database. That is also not a big deal if i m using drawinrect function. But now i want to display a rich text i.e. The text can be bold or italic. 
How to write such rich text in a bounded rectangle...???

I can have text in html format. 
Any solution for this???

Comment: I solved this problem. I am using attributed string parsed from html string. My requirements are now achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Initialize an attributed string. 
NSString *html = text;
NSData *data = [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// Create attributed string from HTML
NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:data baseURL:nil documentAttributes:NULL];
//  CGColorRef red = CGColorCreate(rgbColorSpace, components); CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace); 
//  CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(attrString, CFRangeMake(0, 50),kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, red);
// Create the framesetter with the attributed string.
CTFramesetterRef framesetter =  CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(string);
// Create the frame and draw it into the graphics context 
CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter,CFRangeMake(0, 0), path, NULL);
CFRelease(framesetter); 
CTFrameDraw(frame, pdfContext); 
CFRelease(frame);
```

This solved my issue :)